# Drawing in GtkDrawingArea by other application

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, gtk, xlib

As I mentioned in the title, I have two programs: first, that creates a GtkWindow, GtkDrawingArea and returns the GtkDrawingArea window's XID. The second one recieves that XID and performs some operations on it (resizing, drawing..etc). Resizing works, but if I draw I don't see anything on my GtkDrawingArea (It's still clear). As it seems, the problem is in GtkDrawingArea configuration (for drawing), XID is right. Here's a sample code, that I use to test it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkX11

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

drawing_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
drawing_area.set_size_request(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
drawing_area.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.ALL_EVENTS_MASK)
drawing_area.set_double_buffered(False)
drawing_area.realize()

window = Gtk.Window()
window.add(drawing_area)

window.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()

# Just for sure
drawing_area.get_window().resize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

xid = drawing_area.get_window().get_xid()
print('APP_XID=%s' % xid)

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Instead use `Gtk.Socket` and `Gtk.Plug` (unfortunately X11 only, but if you are using the XID then this is X11 only to begin with.)

Comment: @ptomato Okay, but is it possible to create a Gtk.Socket in first app, and draw on it in the second without creating a Gtk.Plug? (I tried to create XWindow from Socket's ID, but then I can only change window's geometry - nothing is drawn.

Comment: No. `Gtk.Socket` and `Gtk.Plug` must be paired.

Comment: So is there any option to do it in pure Xlib?

Comment: Possibly, but GTK will overdraw the window unless you use the socket and plug system.

Answer (score 0):

This is now done by creating a shared memory via "memfd_create" and rendering into this memory area. Both sides map the memory into a drawable via "cairo_image_surface_create_for_data". It's very straight forward.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I asked this question 3 years ago, but maybe someone with similar problem will find this and your answer will help them.